# how to integrate my app into `Facebook` app in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

How to integrate my app into `facebook` app in iOS? [like this screen(jasper app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuZRt.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
    #import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
    #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>   

 //Download facebook from facebook developer site and implement the following methods.

     -(void)doLoginInFacebook:(UIViewController *)viewController
        {
            FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
            [login logOut];
            [login setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount];
            [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
             {
                 if (error)
                 {
                     //NSLog(@"Error===%@",error);
                 }
                 else if (result.isCancelled)
                 {
                     // Handle cancellations
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     //NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);


                     if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
                     {
                         [self fetchUserInfoWithViewController:viewController];
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         [self fetchUserInfoWithViewController:viewController];

                     }
                 }
             }];

        }
        -(void)fetchUserInfoWithViewController:(UIViewController *)ViewController
        {
            if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
            {
                //NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);

                [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location ,friends ,hometown , friendlists"}]
                 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                     if (!error)
                     {
                         NSMutableDictionary *dic=result;
                         //NSLog(@"%@",dic);

                         if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(doGetFacebookUserInfo:)] )
                         {
                             [self.delegate doGetFacebookUserInfo:dic];
                         }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         // [self.delegate doGetFacebookUserInfo:nil];
                         //NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
                     }
                 }];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The functionality that you want to integrate is known as **"Facebook Advert"**.

You need to advertise your app in facebook.

You can get many answer for this in google.

This is the link for your [reference](https://www.facebook.com/business/ads-guide/app-installs?toggle0=Photo).